# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string i

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a registation page and succesfully created it and want to validitate it to only one email account so that a user can create an account by an email only once and the next time it should give an error saying you have already registered with the email account but in the trail I got an error saying the fallowing

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on string 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\register.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\register.php on line 20
```

and my php registration code is as fallows

```
<?php
include('connection.php');  
$form = $_POST;
$username = $form['username'];
$password = $form['password'];
$repass = $form['repass'];
$email = $form['email'];
$date = $form['date'];
$month = $form['month'];
$year = $form['year'];
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo "Invalid email please type a valid one"; 
}
else{
if($username !='' && $password !='' && $repass!='' && $email !='' && 
$date!='' && $month !='' && $year !='')
{
if($password == $repass)
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where email = :email AND username = 
:username";
$query->bindParam(':username',$username);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email);
$count1 = $query->rowCount();
if($count> 0)
{
    echo "soryy the email you are trying to register is already 
registered!";
}
else{

$insert = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users 
(username,password,email,date,month,year)  values (:username, :password, 
:email, :date, :month, :year)");
$insert->bindParam(':username',$username);
$insert->bindParam(':password',$password);
$insert->bindParam(':email',$email);
$insert->bindParam(':date',$date);
$insert->bindParam(':month',$month);
$insert->bindParam(':year',$year);
$out = $insert->execute();
if(isset($out)){
    echo "thankyou you have sucessfully registered";
}
else{
    echo " sorry some error occured please try again!";
}
} 
}
else{
echo " passwords do not match";
die();
}
}
else{
echo " you have not filled the registration form completely so please it";
}
}
?>
```

can anyone help me out in solving the issue thankyou

Comment: `$select = $connection->prepare($query)` and then `$select->bindParam(':username',$username)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bind params on prepared statement. change select query statement to

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = :email AND username = 
:username");
```

**EDIT**

To count number of rows from select query use `fetchColumn`. Also you are assigning value to `$count1`   and using `$count`. So use same variable name

```
$count = $query->fetchColumn();
if($count> 0)
{
    echo "soryy the email you are trying to register is already 
registered!";
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer it got worked but it has an issue it it It is even registering the person with same email  multiple times but according to the code written by me it should not do it , it have to only create anly one account with a paticular email  can you please review it

Comment: and also the count in if() statment is changed to count1 but I can't find where the error is

Comment: change `$query->rowCount();` to  `$query->fetchColumn()` then try

Comment: it is not working even now but I dont understand what's the difference previously I have created the l used rowCount() then it got worked but now it's not and have also used fetchColumn() but not working it is sucessfully registering into the database

Answer (score 2):

you are not declaring a statement and directly binding params to query use something like this.

```
$select = $connection->prepare($query); 
$select->bindParam(':username',$username);
```